# how to perform FOR XML in SQL Query without column name

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm outputting a XML formatted response in a select statement.

The XML schema goes: `Placemark->MultiGeometry->Polygon-><more children>`
I'm using existing data.

The table I am running with, let's call it table1, has a name (varchar datatype), style (varchar datatype), and geometry (XML datatype)

The values of the geometry field have pre-formatted xml already.  The root tag for each value for all records is MultiGeometry.

Here's the problem.

If I perform:

```
select name, style, geometry from table1 
for xml path('Placemark'), ELEMENTS
```

I receive this:

```
<Placemark>
      <Name>stuff</Name>
       <style>style stuff</style>
         <Geometry> 
            <MultiGeometry>...xml...</MultiGeometry>
         </Geometry>
</Placemark>
```

This fails schema, because the schema (kml schemas) require that MultiGeometry is the child tag inside PLacemark, and the schema does not recognize the `<Geometry>` tag.

I need this:

```
<Placemark>
    <Name>stuff</Name>
      <style>style stuff</style>
        <MultiGeometry>...xml...</MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```

but trying:

```
select name, style, geometry as [ ] 
from table1 for xml path('Placemark'), ELEMENTS
```

fails the query.

How do I get to where I can put MultiGeometry in Placemark without a intermediate tag (Such as `<Geometry>`)?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like.....

```
SELECT CAST( 
          REPLACE(
              REPLACE(CAST((select name, style, [Geometry]  AS [ReplaceMe]
                            from Table1 
                             for xml path('Placemark'),ELEMENTS) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                     , '<ReplaceMe>' , '')
               , '</ReplaceMe>' , '') AS XML)
```

Comment: I like the idea, however, sometimes the XML is really large.  I was hoping to not have to run functions on it.  If this is truly the only way, so be it.  I am going to hold on for just a while longer to see other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```
select name, style, geometry.query('.')
from table1
for xml path('Placemark'), type, ELEMENTS;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - Worked like a charm. Much appreciated.